# Keeping up with algebra

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I just graduated from Cal with a degree in Applied Mathematics. I'm gonna be starting work in a more computer science field but I'd really like to keep up with reading about Algebra post grad so I'm consistently refreshing my knowledge. Any books that you all can recommend for some revision reading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At my blog,I wrote a very extensive set of reviews of advanced undergraduate and first year graduate texts. I think you'll find them very helpful.

http://tableschairsandbeermugsmathemagician.blogspot.com/2015/07/normal-0-false-false-false-en-us-x-none.html

http://tableschairsandbeermugsmathemagician.blogspot.com/2015/08/normal-0-false-false-false-en-us-x-none.html#links

I plan to spend a lot more time writing at the blog soon,so feel free to browse the rest of it and tell your friends.

Comment: This is great! Just finished reading your intro blurb and I can't tell you enough how much I've experienced and witness then professor/textbook difficulty first hand! Looking forward to working through your recommended readings. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

A First Course in Abstract Algebra, 7th Edition

[https://www.amazon.com/First-Course-Abstract-Algebra-7th/dp/0201763907](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201763907)

Comment: For self study..complete solution manual also available

Comment: Your Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be working in the computer science field, I strongly suggest you look for books which are relevant in the applied realm. [Here](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com/2013/09/the-best-books-for-linear-algebra.html) is a collection of books that are worthwhile to own.